# For what should one use the annotated-posts page?

Tags: support

When I was searching for a question in Google I just found this [page with Annotated Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/annotated-posts) in SO.
But I didn't find any help about this page, nor a link for it in SO.

Why does it exist? For what would one use it?

Comment: Looks like a good place to see all bountied questions regardless of tags.

Comment: Related: [List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76566/21960)

Comment: Looks like everything there is closed, migrated or locked. That's probably the "annotation".

Comment: It's probably aimed at moderators, to provide them an easy method of keeping track of these posts. The page is mentioned at [What are these notices under my post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165006/167646) and [Alert a moderator when an answer is improved after a post notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135786/167646)

Comment: @ale thanks. Now that question are among my favorites.

Comment: Google probably shouldn't be indexing it.